# Why isn't my mongoose document updated properly inside of the bcrypt functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bcrypt

I am trying to hash a password right before save is called on a document. I attempt to generate a hash (which works fine) and then update the password field of the document (a string type) with the new hashed password.

However, the `user.password = hash` line doesn't change anything.

I check my database and nothing has changed! Whats even weirder is that if I try to change my doc's data *outside* the hash/bcrypt functions, it works fine.

For example, if I initialize my document with the password *"fake1"* and then put `user.password = "fakepassword"` outside of my hashing functions, it updates it fine....

Why is that? Does the reference `this` change once you enter does hashing functions? Every example (I've searched for hours and hours) I've seen is exactly like mine... why does mine not work?

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {   
    var user = this; // i reference the doc by "this"
    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err,salt){    
        if(err){  
            console.log("error with salt \n");  
        }  
            bcrypt.hash(user.password,salt,function(error,hash){  
                if (error){  
                    console.log("error with hash \n");  
                }  
                user.password = hash; // this line doesn't do anything!  

            });  
   });        
   return next(user);                                                                                                                                                    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `next()` when the asynchronous bcrypt code is done. Right now, you're calling it without waiting for the result of `bcrypt.genSalt/bcrypt.hash`.

Also, the argument passed to `next` is reserved for errors. You should call `next` without an argument if everything went okay.

Here's a cleaned up version of your middleware:

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this;
  bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error with salt \n");
      // Pass error back to Mongoose.
      return next(err);
    }
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(error, hash) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("error with hash \n");
        return next(error);
      }
      user.password = hash;
      // Here are we done with the bcrypt stuff, so it's time to call `next`
      next();
    });
  });
});
```